# PostgreSQL cannot work when opens SSL on Windows 10

Tags: ssl, postgresql, database

I am not sure this topic will fit here but I don't know ask it where.

I am trying to open the SSL of PostgreSQL 10.16 on Windows10.

I read a lot of documents about creating an SSL certificate to PostgreSQL but documents spend on Windows 10 are rare and don't detail.

These are the steps which I did:

**Step 1**, I download the OpenSSL version of Windows from
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

and install it with the path C:\OpenSSL-Win64, setting system variable.

**Step 2**, I use cmd.exe run as an admin to create server.key with command line:

```
genrsa -out server.key 4096
```

, setting appropriate permission and owner on the private key file (here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463654)

```
icacls server.key /reset

icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
```

and I got a response from cmd.exe in this command-line

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>icacls server.key /reset
processed file:  server.key
Successfully processed 1 file; Failed processing 0 files

C:\WINDOWS\system32>icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
processed file:  server.key
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

continue to create the server certificate:

```
req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key server.key -out server.crt
```

**Step 3**, since I am self-signing, I use the server certificate as the trusted root certificate, so I have 3 files: server.key, server.crt, and root.crt (this is a copy of server crt)

I move these three files to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data

**Step 4**, I am setting postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
ssl=on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

and add command-line to the end of pg_hba.conf:

```
# IPv4 remote connections for authenticated users
hostssl   all     postgres             0.0.0.0/0            md5 clientcert=1
```

**Finally**, I get an error as below when I restart my PostgreSQL

```
The PostgreSQL -x64-10 -PostgreSQL Server 10 service on the Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
```

and in my log of PostgreSQL:

```
2021-03-28 16:35:44.735 +07 [7624] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-28 16:34:51 +07

2021-03-28 16:35:45.099 +07 [7044] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

2021-03-28 17:39:37.827 +07 [7044] LOG:  received fast shutdown request

2021-03-28 17:39:37.834 +07 [7044] LOG:  aborting any active transactions

2021-03-28 17:39:37.839 +07 [7044] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 7972) exited with exit code 1

2021-03-28 17:39:37.843 +07 [7880] LOG:  shutting down

2021-03-28 17:39:37.877 +07 [7044] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I suspect PostgreSQL did not read the 3 files that I put in its data directory.

I have referenced these documents

https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959324/chmod-og-rwx-server-key-in-windows/51463654#51463654

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ssl-tcp.html

I have been messing with it for many days and I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you verified that Postgres starts normally if you set `ssl=off`?

Comment: My Postgres activities normally when I set ssl=off. But I noticed a mention in this document (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ssl-tcp.html). It mentions that "PostgreSQL has native support for using SSL connections to encrypt client/server communications for increased security. This requires that "OpenSSL is installed on both client and server systems and that support in PostgreSQL is enabled at build time". So this thing means that I have to install PostgreSQL from Source Code and enabled it by command line (--with-openssl) , am I right?

Comment: Did you compile PostgreSQL yourself? Because yes, you need to include "SSL"  support in it. They are prebuilt Windows packages at https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ why not using them? Why I don't know first hand I pretty much assume with high probability that they are compiled as needed.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I am using Postgres 10.16 which comes from packages on Windows 10. I get errors as you know. I doubt it isn't with SSL support compiled in.

Comment: I am trying to check my Postgres version "Does it includes SSL support in it?"